# Pluralization of "Mal" in "several times"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

> I went to the cinema several times during my stay in Berlin.

My translation would be

> Ich ging während meines Aufenthalts in Berlin mehrere Male ins Kino.

Is it correct to pluralize "Mal" here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It's correct. In colloquial speech people also say:

> Ich bin mehrmals ins Kino gegangen.

Comment: Oder weniger hilfsverblastig: `Ich ging mehrmals (mehrere Male) ins Kino.`

Comment: @userunknown... aber im ganzen Zusammenhang: "Als ich in Berlin war, ging ich mehrere Male ins Kino." Doch eher nicht, oder?

Comment: Wieso nicht? Tötet die Hilfsverben wo Ihr sie findet!

Comment: @userunknown... dann geh mal nach Süddeutschland... da ist alles voll davon ;)